# Broadcom 4360 and Ubuntu 20.04 on Macbook Air 2015

Tags: drivers, 20.04, broadcom, macbook

I am trying different solutions for this machine but nothing seems to work.

Hardware details:

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:

02:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

As reported in the table, I should use the bcmwl-kernel-source, which almost works but the connection gets stuck intermittently.
So, it looks like it is connected but it does not work, unless I disconnect it and reconnect it again.

Does anyone have a similar issue or can suggest something to try on this device?

I tried alternate drivers (the non-proprietary ones, as suggested elsewhere) but none of them seem to work at all (the network card does not turn on).

Comment: sorry, I wanted to post this question as an answer to the question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Please don't post questions as an answer to another question.

Comment: yes, of course. luckily, I couldn't do it! :)

Answer (score 1):

After an automatic software update in Jan 2021 for Ubuntu 20.04 on my MacBook Air 2015 I couldn't enter the wireless network settings anymore.

I managed to get it working again, but I tried many failing recommendations so I'm not sure what steps can be left out and neither can I  remember all steps taken.
Here's what I think are the essential steps:

```
broadcom-sta-dkms is a proprietary driver. Ensure you have enabled this under 'Software & Updates / Ubuntu Software'

sudo apt update
sudo apt remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get remove --purge  bcmwl-kernel-source
Reboot your computer
```

And finally the step that made it work again

```
sudo apt install --reinstall broadcom-sta-dkms
Then reboot your computer
```

I'm aware some of these commands overlap and even some commands might not be required, but since my computer is working now I can't verify a simplified procedure.